# Jquery Function to display Loading icon on whole page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a price calculation function that calculate price on loading for 5 seconds then displays price of products.The image path is in LOADINGIMG variable. I want to call it on the page that is shows that loading image only on page then after 5 seconds when time finishes it displays the results as usual. Please help me. Thank you

```
function CalculatePrice() {

    var req, parameters, datasend, prodlist;

    LOADING = setInterval(function () {
        $('.objprice', prodlist).html(LOADINGIMG);
    }, 5);

    var querystring = "?" + BASIC_PARA + "&" + GetPriceCalculationQueryString() + "&filter=" + FILTER + "&sort=1&FilterChange=0&cacheprod=0";
    if (PAGE_TYPE < 3) {
        querystring = querystring + "&dumy=1",
            datasend = "";
    } else {

        req = {
            RefID: REFIDLIST
        };
        datasend = JSON.stringify(req);
        datasend = encodeURIComponent(datasend);
    }
    URL_QUERYSTRING = querystring;
    UpdateLabels();
    Searchcontrol(2);
    if (ISREFID == "" && LANDWITHPRICE == false) {

        smoothScroll('prodlistinsp', 300);
    }
    parameters = "prodrq=" + datasend;

    if (document.domain.indexOf("localhost") != -1 || document.domain.indexOf("tenbook") != -1) {
        makeRequest(TENWEB_PATH + "/inspiration/PriceCalculatorPage.aspx" + querystring, parameters);
    } else {
        makeRequest("http://" + document.domain + "/" + PROXYPAGE + querystring, parameters);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid the `setInterval` for this. Just display the `LOADINGIMG` when the function is called, and put a `setTimeout` inside it.

When you're done doing your calculations, the timeout will display your result.